# Changing emacs bindings on Mac OS X for command to be meta

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm using GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.29) of 2010-05-08 on black.local on OS X.  I downloaded it from here: http://emacsformacosx.com/

My problem is that it doesn't have the command keys mapped to the normal emacs Meta bindings - it has them mapped to what an osx user knows Command-v is now 'cut' for example when I do a describe-keybinding.

How can I get rid of these osx bindings, and make Command mapped back to the normal gnu Meta bindings?

Answer (score 8):

Found it here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsFAQ

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
```

Comment: Yes, Aquamacs' claim to Apple compatibility is that it overlays Apple's GUI's key bindings over Emacs's.  Gnu/Carbon Emacs already uses command as meta and works the way you always thought Emacs did.

Comment: Then add (setq mac-option-modifier nil) to reenable the alt key

Comment: Wha if you decide to use the terminal?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus You can use `option` instead in the terminal if you follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1856502/56488

Comment: Thanks! However `left-shift` key is still my ideal choice.

Answer (score 2):

Try [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) (Works on all macs - despite the name). It allows remapping practically every key on your keyboard (even stuff like different mappings to left and right shift).

When you define your own mappings in a xml file you can use all kinds of fancy options like Application specific mappings and device specific mappings.

You can also alter the keys comfortable in stock emacs with `M-x customize-group RET ns RET`

A tip - as some people need the alt key to input special characters is to map 'left alt' to 'fn' and set emacs to use 'fn' as 'meta'.

Comment: +1 for `M-x customize-group RET ns RET`